# Does spring-cloud-dataflow provide support for local scheduling for tasks yet?

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-dataflow-ui

Hi im trying to add scheduler to SCDF tasks ? Is this possible on the local machine server ?

Answer (score 0):

The `local` scheduler is not supported to schedule tasks in SCDF. You can read more info on this [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-scheduler-quartz/pull/1)